# How do you return from a method?

Tags: objective-c

I have this call: (Velocity is a CGPoint)

```
float velY = Velocity.y;
velY = [self DoJump:velY :gT];
```

To this:

```
- (float) DoJump:(float) velocityY:(ccTime) GameTime
{

   return velocityY;
}
```

but im getting an error at the call saying incompatible types. Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you pass to the function, but your definition looks wrong. It should be more like:

```
- (float) DoJump:(float)velocityY andTime:(ccTime) GameTime
```

and then you call it with

```
velY = [self DoJump:velY andTime:gT];
```

Make sure to pass `float` and `ccTime` types to the method.

Comment: And make sure the method declaration is known prior to using it, i.e. place it in your .h file.